# Restarting process in CentOS if server restarts

Tags: bash, centos, java, cron, bash-scripting

I have a VPS with some Java applications (made with "Play Framework") running on ports 9000, 9001, 9002 and 9003. VPS Provider (iPage) happens to reboot servers unexpectedly from time to time, leaving all four processes down.

The processes I run are launched by

- `nohup ./start -Dhttp.port=9000`,
- `nohup ./start -Dhttp.port=9001`,
- `nohup ./start -Dhttp.port=9002`, and
- `nohup ./start -Dhttp.port=9003`

with all four `start` launchers made by "Play" and located in different folders (inside `/opt`).

Each time iPage reboots my VPS, all four folders keep their 'RUNNING_PID' file with their former PID, so I have to manually delete those files to be able to put them up again.

I was checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697064/1764416) of a relatively similar question ([How do I write a bash script to restart a process if it dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/696839/1764416)) (without port specifying and `nohup` style, I guess) without success.

This is what I've made so far:

- Made a `tryReboot` file (saved into `/opt/myJavaApp9000/`) with the following content:

  ```
  until start -Dhttp.port=9000; do
      echo "9000 process crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
      sleep 1
  done
  ```
- Added `@reboot /opt/myJavaApp9000/tryReboot` to the `crontab` file by using `crontab -e`

After rebooting the server (via iPage Reboot) all four of them kept their `RUNNING_PID` files, but none of them restarted. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What could be the problem?  Here are some possibilities:

- Reread the answer you referred to. 
  `until [start -Dhttp.port=9000]; do` should not have the `[` and `]` brackets.
- If you have **`.`** (the current directory) in your search path,
  you shouldn’t need to say `./` when you run your `start` program the way you do now. 
  If you *don’t* have **`.`** in your search path,
  you *do* need to say `./start` in your `tryReboot` script.
- Your `tryReboot` script could be not running from `crontab` for any number of reasons. 
  For example, at the risk of insulting your intelligence,
  you don’t say that you have done `chmod +x tryReboot`. 
  Have you verified that `tryReboot` is running? 
  Perhaps by having it write messages to a log file? 
  Hint: you might want to include the date&time in those messages
  by including `$(date)` in your `echo` string.
- The `RUNNING_PID` files could be persisting because there’s no mechanism for removing them. 
  (If you’ve said how you expect them to get removed, I missed it.) 
  You should probably delete the `RUNNING_PID` file at the beginning of the `tryReboot` script;
  and, indeed, probably in each iteration
  (because, if you get to the `echo` statement, that means that the `start` command has terminated).

But it’s hard to tell what ***is*** the problem, because your question is a little unclear.

- Is `start` the name of your program, and are you really launching it
  with a command like `nohup ./start -Dhttp.port=port_number &`,
  or is `start` a program that forks and runs your program in an asynchronous child process? 
  If the latter, the whole `until command; do … done` approach is inappropriate.
- Have you tried running `tryReboot` manually?  What happens?

Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd already done `chmod +x tryReboot`, but I hadn't realised the script wasn't running. When i do `./tryReboot` it says "./tryReboot: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token 'done' ./tryReboot: line 4: 'done'
"... Made the `tryReboot` simpler, and put:

_until start; do
    echo "Server 'myserver' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 5
done_

Without any change. Regarding your other questions, start is the launcher of the Java Applications I've made (that's the way Play Framework does it) :S

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). It is designed specifically for this task. There is no need to re-invent the wheel.

simply edit /etc/monit/monitrc, add the path to your script and you are done.